# Route error response and http status (4xx, 5xx) using Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Looks like easy task and basic feature but I'm not able to figure out how to solve this problem. I've read multiple sources, tried multiple solutions, but no luck.

I have two spring-boot rest apps let's name them: ProxyApp & BusinessApp. ProxyApp is called by Angular frontend and contains Swagger annotations to generate TS/Angular client. BusinessApp has business logic and is returning OK response or ErrorResponse (used Spring @ControllerAdvice). I need to route both: body and also http status from BusinessApp via ProxyApp. But WebClient re-sets status (e.g. 400) coming from BusinessApp to 200.

```java
    @Operation(summary = "Some desc")
    @PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))
    })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String someMethod() {

        // skipped

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .onErrorMap(WebClientRequestException.class, ex -> new RestApiUnavailableException(ex,"some msg"))
                .block();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webClient code returns 200 because of the line `.onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())`.

If you return `Mono.empty()` while handling the error status, it will suppress the error and proceed with the normal response, as described in the documentation of `onStatus()` method:

> To suppress the treatment of a status code as an error and process it as a normal response, return Mono.empty() from the function. The response will then propagate downstream to be processed.

On error response, WebClient throws `WebClientResponseException` by default. It contains all the required information, so in order to pass the error response through the proxy just create an exception handler as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(WebClientResponseException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(WebClientResponseException e) {
       return ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode().value()).body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());

    }
}
```

Make sure to get remove your `onStatus()` call so that your call looks like that:

```
return webClient.post()
        .uri(url)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue(request)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .onErrorMap(WebClientRequestException.class, ex -> new RestApiUnavailableException(ex,"some msg"))
        .block();
```

That way, you will intercept the exception thrown by WebClient and pass the response with the appropriate status code and body.

As a side note, keep in mind that calling `block()` denies the benefits of reactive stack and is generally discouraged.

Comment: Great, thank you, working as expected, I just added to the exception handler .contentType(Optional.ofNullable(e.getHeaders().getContentType()).orElse(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))